# Form not submitting on text click

Tags: php, javascript

This isthe form which i am submitting it through on click on text, but the values are not passing on the action page.

```
  <form action="forget_pass.php" method="post" id="new_user" name="new_user">
  <ul class="inputlist">
    <li><span class="redcolor">*</span>Email Address or Phone No.</li>
    <li>
      <input name="" class="inputbox" type="text" name="EmailAddress" id="txtEmail" />
      &nbsp;&nbsp;

      </li>

     <li class="rightalign">
     <a href="javascript:document.new_user.submit();" onclick="">
      Retrieve Password</a></li>

    </form>
```

Comment: You should put `document.forms['new_user'].submit();` inside the `<a onclick`

Comment: Try removing the empty `name` attribute for the `input` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input name="" class="inputbox" type="text" name="EmailAddress" id="txtEmail" />
```

Should be

```
<input class="inputbox" type="text" name="EmailAddress" id="txtEmail" />
```

-

```
<a href="javascript:document.new_user.submit();" onclick="">
```

should be better to be

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.new_user.submit();return false;">
```

Comment: Or javascript:void(0) and you can avoid the return false;

Comment: Thx just fond the bug by minimizing the content ..thx a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

here is the working code you can use

```
<form action="forget_pass.php" method="post" id="new_user" name="new_user">
  <ul class="inputlist">
    <li><span class="redcolor">*</span>Email Address or Phone No.</li>
    <li>
      <input class="inputbox" type="text" name="EmailAddress" id="txtEmail" />
      &nbsp;&nbsp;

      </li>

     <li class="rightalign">
     <a href="javascript:document.new_user.submit();">
      Retrieve Password</a></li>

    </form>
```

Problems in your code are

1- you have two name attributes. one is empty

2- onclick not used properly...

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code,

```
<form action="forget_pass.php" method="post" id="new_user" name="new_user">
  <ul class="inputlist">
    <li><span class="redcolor">*</span>Email Address or Phone No.</li>
    <li>
      <input class="inputbox" type="text" name="emailAddress" id="txtEmail" >
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      </li>
     <li class="rightalign">
     <a href="javascript:submitForm();">
      Retrieve Password</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

And the javaScript code is,

```
submitForm = function(){
    alert(document.forms[0].emailAddress.value);
document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

And the running code is this http://jsfiddle.net/4AWW6/